# I have a problem with the '?' operator. Why doesn't this line do what it should?

Tags: c++

Please explain me why I need to add the parenthesis for this line of code to do what I want. Thank you! I really have no idea.

```
cout << n - 2*m > 0  ? n - 2*m : 0 << ' '; // for n = 3, m = 3, it prints -3 instead of 0
cout << (n - 2*m > 0  ? n - 2*m : 0) << ' '; // here it works
```

When I try it in this form it still works, i just can't see the problem.

```
n = n - 2*m > 0  ? n - 2*m : 0 << ' ';
cout << n;
//here i dont need to add the parenthesis
```

Comment: Two things you can search for: "ternary operator" and "operator precedence".

Comment: Look up rules of operator precedence.

Comment: There was a tool called *parenthesizer* that would add parentheses around subexpressions based on the operator precedence.  It was useful to help learn what the parser was seeing, helping people internalize the precedence order (which is mostly common sense based on experience, but there are some odd edge cases... such as this situation).  Unfortunately, the website is 503.  :-(

Comment: The ternary operator tend to make code much harder to read, understand and maintain. And can even introduce subtle bugs like you have. It's often much better to use plain `if ... else ...`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence